# Error when Importing an existing gradle project into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA and i am trying to import an existing gradle project in my desktop , i have selected  the import Project icon and then i gave the path to build.gradle file of the project i want to import , but i am getting this error :

```
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '1.9'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle.build-scan:com.gradle.build-scan.gradle.plugin:1.9')

Searched in the following repositories: Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Could any one help  solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version of the gradle project you're importing is either compatible or the same version (the latter being most preferable since it keeps things clean). Some plugins are not backwards compatible so you'll have to check on gradle's website.

Here's a link about gradle's build scan plugin that may help: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.build-scan/1.12.1

Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by "the version of gradle project" , and how to check for that ?

Comment: Like programs, libraries are usually updated every so often to keep things running nicely (or as nicely as a library will run because they're painful). For gradle, I'm not sure how they store their library imports but I know for similar projects like maven they're stored in json files.